# Error Message: The argument type 'List<Null>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'

Tags: flutter

How to fix this error? Error Message: The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.

My Code

```
CheartDraw(
controller: _controller,
height: 500,
backgroundColor: Colors.white, width: null,
)
```

[image]

Comment: Not a flutter developer but I don't think width can be `null`. Try setting it to a valid value like 100, 500 etc.

Comment: remove width property or assign `0` as a value

Comment: Do you have a solution? Please share.

Comment: Can you include what is `CheartDraw`?

Comment: @nagendranag shared it

Comment: ``width`` can't be null and it can be any double value.

Comment: patientPreviousDocument: _patientDocument, patientDocument: [], patientPrescription: null,);  How bout this. patientPrescription: null,); Same problem.

Comment: width can not be null it expected double . try this `width:100`

Comment: What inside `CheartDraw`, can you share code for the same?